TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str when running Python script
I have run the following Python script to remove duplcates between two json files based on userid:
    import json

    with open("target_user.json", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f1:
        target = json.load(f1)
    with open("source_user.json", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f2:
        source = json.load(f2)
            
    target2 = []
    for item in target:
       if item['userid'] not in [x['userid'] for x in source]:
            target2.append(item)
            
    with open('target_user2.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as nf:
        json.dump(target2, nf, indent=4)
        

It generates errors:
    TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

from this line:
    if item['userid'] not in [x['userid'] for x in source]:

I have tried the following, but it does not fix:
    if dict([item]['userid']) not in [dict[x]['userid'] for x in source]:    

Here is a sample of my json file:
    {
        "567897068": {
            "userid": "567897068",
            "status": "UserStatus.OFFLINE",
            "name": "btb appeal",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "None"
        },
        "5994781619": {
            "userid": "5994781619",
            "status": "UserStatus.OFFLINE",
            "name": "Ahh",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "hourng999"
        },
        "1873973169": {
            "userid": "1873973169",
            "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
            "name": "Chanthy",
            "bot": false,
            "username": "Alis_Thy"
        }
    }

Any help is appreciated.
I have tried the followings advised by John, but it does not:
    import json

    with open("target_user.json", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f1:
        target = json.load(f1)
    with open("source_user.json", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f2:
        source = json.load(f2)
            
    target2 = []
    for item in target.values():
       # print(item) # print scanned results on CMD
        #if item['userid'] not in [x['userid'] for x in source]:
        #if item['userid'] not in [x['userid'] for x in source]:
        if target[item]['userid'] not in [source[x]['userid'] for x in source]:
            target2.append(item)
            
    with open('target_user2.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as nf:
        json.dump(target2, nf, indent=4)


I found out that there is an error in the second json file, that is why there is error mentioned. My original codes are working well. the correct format of that second file is:
    [
           {
                "userid": "567897068",
                "status": "UserStatus.OFFLINE",
                "name": "btb appeal",
                "bot": false,
                "username": "None"
            },
            {
                "userid": "5994781619",
                "status": "UserStatus.OFFLINE",
                "name": "Ahh",
                "bot": false,
                "username": "hourng999"
            },
            {
                "userid": "1873973169",
                "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
                "name": "Chanthy",
                "bot": false,
                "username": "Alis_Thy"
            }
    ]

It is different from the first file; that was why the original codes dont work - both files must have the same format. Thanks

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

target is a dictionary.
When you iterate over a dictionary with for item in target, it returns the keys of the dictionary, which are strings.
So on the first loop iteration, item is the string "567897068", which causes the error.
I think you intended to iterate over the values of the dictionary instead of the keys:
for item in target.values():


Hi John, thank you for a quick help. I have tried both solutions provided, they dont work. Any suggestions? Cheers

@JamesBlack You have the exact same issue with x['userid'] for x in source.  Did you also fix that loop to use .values()  instead of iterating over the dictionary directly?

@JamesBlack  Also, saying "I tried this and it didn't work" is a terrible way to describe the problem.  We need to see actual code and the actual full error traceback message.

Dear John, I have updated your advice. Thanks

target is a nested dictionary. If you try to iterate as for item in target, it's the same as for item in target.keys(). Than, the content you are looking for will be a value, represented by the next dictionary. Only in that dictionary "userid" will be a key.
You can try to access it like target[item]["userid"], not item["userid"]. Just like this:
for item in target:
    if target[item]['userid'] not in [source[x]['userid'] for x in source]:
            target2.append(item)

Another way to do it, as mentioned by previous answer is using for item in target.values() for item to become an inner dictionary and to have access to "userid". Don't mix it with previous solution.
for item in target.values():
    if item['userid'] not in [x['userid'] for x in source.values()]:
            target2.append(item)

Moreover, if source_user.json has the same structure as "target_user.json", than [source[x]['userid'] for x in source] will have the same issue. I already shown how to deal with it in code above.

Hi Andreiev, I have also tried the second solution: for item in target.values():
if item['userid'] not in [x['userid'] for x in source.values()]:
target2.append(item); it does not work either. Thanks
